# Newly Planted Autumn Blaze Appears to Be Dying

Tags: trees, diagnosis

Planted our Autumn Blaze about 10 days ago in central NC (clay soil).  Normally this time of the year we'd be seeing the start of fall, but we've had an abnormally hot and dry run of 90 degree days and no rain for 2+ weeks (and none in the forecast for another week or two).  While the Prairiefire Crabapple we planted nearby at the same time is thriving, our Autumn Blaze appears to be dying.  It's drooped considerably and the top has turned brown.  We're watering for a few minutes in the early morning.  Despite the heat and dryness and only watering for a bit, the soil around it appears to be wet at all times. We tried skipping a day or two of watering with no difference.  Any ideas?  Are we underwatering?  Overwatering?  Soil too compact?  Is this just transplant shock?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: How deep and how wide of a hole did you dig? Did you put the soil you took out for the tree back into the hole, or did you replace it with "good top soil"?

Comment: What you want to do is make sure it gets about 2 inches or so of water a week. I would water it deeply twice a week instead of every day, unless is's super hot out. Next time you plant a tree try planting it a little higher and make a saucer of dirt around it.